# How to create exponential growth in excel over a year

Tags: excel, exponential

So I am trying to build an excel model where every month the numbers will increase exponentially to a point at the end of the year which is driven by annual expectations. Currently I have it divided by 12 and each year there are huge jumps over the previous making the chart/growth very jumpy. For illustration purposes, lets say for 2020 the desired number for the year is 12. In the current state, I would get 1 per month (12/12), however, what I want is for it to be growing gradually/exponentially, so for example 0.2, 0.5, 0.9 etc with December being the largest, and the sum for the entire year equaling 12. Then the next year (2021), starting in January, it would take into account the December 2020 number and grow from there again to the desired number (lets say total 24 for 2021) and so on. I'd love for it to have a more exponential / hockey stick-like growth.

What would be a good way to do this?

Comment: Curves of the form `y = A*e^(kt)` are easily determined by just 2 points via basic algebra. You have specified `y` for `t = 12`. You need 1 more point, say the value at `t = 0`. By the way -- neither `auto` (which has to do with something in C++) or `fill` (which has to do with colors) have anything to do with your question, so I am removing them. Please read the description of a tag before deciding to use it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Here are the real total numbers (annual) starting in 2020:

5  85  510  1,665  3,860  7,335 

What I would basically like to do is growth that is consistently getting larger BUT sums up to the numbers above. While I can make an exponential function, I'm unsure how to make them sum to these numbers (in excel) while consistently growing on a monthly basis.

Comment: An exponential curve has 2 degrees of freedom, but you seem to be imposing more than 2 constraints. Your specification isn't clear and might even be inconsistent. Please clarify. Perhaps you want to do a regression?

Comment: So the numbers I have given above are total sums for how many products a company will develop annually. What I want to do is take these numbers and show them on a monthly basis instead of annual. However, I do not want to do this by taking the sum and dividing by 12, but rather show them as a ramp-up. So that initially it starts with a low number and then exponentially (or however else) grows from month to month but that the total annual sum does not change. Hope I made it clearer. How can I do this in excel with a function or formula?

Answer (score 1):

The function [RRI](https://www.excelfunctions.net/excel-rri-function.html) can be used to find an interest rate which will give you a given target value. This can be used to find terms in a geometric series which have a given sum (which is what you seem to be asking for).

For example, say you want 12 exponentially increasing numbers which, when added to 100, gets you to 2000. Starting with 100, repeatedly multiply by `(1 + RRI(12,100,2000))`. To get the numbers that you want (which will be 12 numbers which sum to 1900) just calculate the difference each month:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way to solve this is by using Goal Seek. First you need to build a sheet like this:

[image: Sheet layout]

You choose the starting value in January (`B1`) and every month is a constant growth rate (`D1`) bigger than the previous month. You also calculate the total sum at the bottom in `B13`.

Now you use goal seek to find the growth rate which makes the sum equal to 12:

[image: Goal seek window]

The answer I get for a starting value of 0.1 is a growth rate of 1.376:

[image]